# Gnuroot - apt install returns permission denied

Tags: linux, debian, android, apt, dpkg

After successfuly [setting up debian stretch](https://nmilosev.svbtle.com/gnuroot-fedora-arch) on [Gnuroot](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=champion.gnuroot&hl=en), I wasn't able to install packages. Running **dpkg -i** on a package returns:
`E: seteuid 0 failed - seteuid (13: Permission denied)` 
`E: setegid 0 failed - setegid (13: Permission denied)`

What could be a possible solution to this?

Comment: This question would be better asked to the developers of Gnuroot, as they know best how their own app works.

Comment: I agree and in fact I did it *some time ago*, but didn't got any response.